# How to move camera with Swipe using new Unity input system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

Using Unity's new input system, I would like to detect a start touch and and end touch. Using these, I'd like to compute the distance and direction for the camera to move, so the camera moves with a "swipe". However, I am having trouble figuring out how to detect these touches in Update().

Pseudocode would be:

```
private void Update() {

// get start position
// get end position
   MoveCameraOnSwipe()
}
```

I've figured out what goes in MoveCameraOnSwipe(), or how to move the camera using a target position and direction. The only part I can't figure out is how to use the new input system to capture the start and end values in Update.

I could try to read the values directly, but not sure how that would work:

We could return values from the touch using this method, where Screen Controls is player input:

```
public Vector2 PrimaryPosition()
    {
        return screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
```

Then in Update() - would I do something like:

```
     screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.started += context => StartTouchPrimary(context);
     screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.canceled += context => EndTouchPrimary(context);
```

But this doesn't seem quite complete. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Register to the events in `OnEnable`, and unregister from them is `OnDisable`.  This prevents hanging references, which can cause memory leaks (since there is a reference tied to the event still).

On `started` store the position to a variable `startPosition`.

```
screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.started += ctx => {
    startPosition = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
```

On `canceled` store the value to a variable `endPosition`.

```
screenControls.SwipeMap.PrimaryContact.canceled += ctx => {
    endPosition = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    // At this point you want to take a copy of the start and end positions,
    // calculate the distance and direction, and start  the camera move
}
```

Make sure to take a copy of the start and end positions (notably the start position) before starting the movement. `startPosition` can be reassigned while the camera movement is taking place (think completing a swipe, and immediately starting a new swipe).

For Update, add a boolean `cameraMoving` which will indicate if your movement function should be running.  The boolean should be set to true when `cancel` happens and set to false when the movement is complete.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (cameraMoving)
    {
        MoveCameraOnSwipe();
    }
}
```

If a new swipe happens while the camera is moving, you can set `startPosition` to the current camera position to prevent the camera jumping back to the new swipes starting position.